# add a task to two timelines

Tags: tasks, task-list, timeline

I want to know if it's possible to add a task to two timelines. I have a task list on a project site that has several timelines to display the tasks by department, but I want to also have a timeline to roll some of the major tasks together on a combined timeline.

Is it possible to add one task to multiple timelines or no?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do exactly what you're asking. But you might be interested in using subtasks. You can create major tasks and then create sub-tasks related back to a major task.

Comment: thanks, but I'm already using sub-tasks. What I'm hoping to do is use multiple timelines to visually show subtasks by department/group and then roll up the major tasks onto a general timeline. My problem is that the major tasks (as well as as the sub tasks) are already on other timelines.

Answer (score 0):

1. Each Task List has its own "Timeline" that can only be seen in a default style view when the timeline check box is checked.
2. there is a *web part* that you can connect to **one** task list called **Project Summary** found under the **content roll up** section that is a timeline.

multiple task lists can not display in one time line, however you can make one page with a couple timeline or "project summary" web parts that all point to their own task lists to help users see it all.